# Hiding divs is only applying to first if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide/show div's when a radio is clicked, based on if a hidden fields value is set or not. The way that my code is set up, only the first grouping is functioning (text1), the rest are not and I'm getting a console message that it "Cannot read property 'value' of null".

I've triple checked my ID names, and if I switch a different ID to be the first in the sequence, it will work, and then the previously first one will not anymore.

I'm not getting any code errors until I click on radio1, but is something not formatted correctly? Is there a better way to list out my text fields that I want to check the values of?

```
$(document).on('click', '#radio1', function() {

if(document.getElementById('text1').value > 0 ) {

         $('#div1').hide();
         $('#div2').hide();
         $('#div3').hide();
         $('#div4').hide();     
}
else if(document.getElementById('text2').value > 0 ) {

         $('#div1').hide();
         $('#div2').hide();
         $('#div3').hide();
         $('#div4').hide();  
}
else if(document.getElementById('text3').value > 0 ) {

         $('#div1').hide();
         $('#div2').hide();
         $('#div3').hide();
         $('#div4').hide();    
}
else  {

         $('#div1').show();
         $('#div2').show();
         $('#div3').show();
         $('#div4').show();

      }

},);
```

Comment: Post your HTML.

Comment: You also have a stray comma before the very last closing parenthesis in the javascript you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You must have an error in your html. Inferring what your html *should* look like, and using your javascript works just fine:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#radio1', function() {

  if (document.getElementById('text1').value > 0) {

    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').hide();
    $('#div4').hide();
  } else if (document.getElementById('text2').value > 0) {

    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').hide();
    $('#div4').hide();
  } else if (document.getElementById('text3').value > 0) {

    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').hide();
    $('#div4').hide();
  } else {

    $('#div1').show();
    $('#div2').show();
    $('#div3').show();
    $('#div4').show();

  }

}, );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

#radio1: <input type="radio" value="1" id="radio1">
<br> #text1: <input id="text1" type="text">
<br> #text2: <input id="text2" type="text">
<br> #text3: <input id="text3" type="text">
<div id="div1">
  one
</div>
<div id="div2">
  two
</div>
<div id="div3">
  three
</div>
<div id="div4">
  four
</div>
```

### Soapbox

And, I might add (because it's 2018) you can do the same thing without jQuery with no extra work:

```
document.getElementById('radio1').addEventListener('click', function() {

    var t1 = document.getElementById('text1'),
    t2 = document.getElementById('text2'),
        t3 = document.getElementById('text3'),
    divs = [
        document.getElementById('div1'),
        document.getElementById('div2'),
        document.getElementById('div3'),
        document.getElementById('div4')
    ];

  if( t1.value  ) {
    for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
      divs[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  else if( t2.value > 0 ) {
    for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
      divs[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  else if( t3.value > 0 ) {
    for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
      divs[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
      divs[i].style.display = 'block';
  }

});
```

And then you can make it even cleaner:

```
document.getElementById('radio1').addEventListener('click', function() {

    var t1 = document.getElementById('text1'),
    t2 = document.getElementById('text2'),
        t3 = document.getElementById('text3'),
    divs = [
        document.getElementById('div1'),
        document.getElementById('div2'),
        document.getElementById('div3'),
        document.getElementById('div4')
    ];

    divs.forEach(function(div){
        if( t1.value || t2.value || t3.value )
            div.style.display = 'none';
       else
            div.style.display = 'block';
  });

});
```